# Pod is restarting when one of container terminates to successful completion

Tags: kubernetes

I have this kind of deployment

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-name
  labels:
    key: value
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      key: value
  template:
    metadata:
      key: value
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: air-run-sa
      containers:
        - name: deployment-main
          image: deployment-image-here
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 5000
              protocol: TCP
        - name: deployment-poll
          image: alpine:3.9
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: [ "/bin/sh" ]
          args:
            - /scripts/user-deployment-poll.sh
# --- snip ---
```

The pod contains two containers- `deployment-main` and `deployment-poll`. The `deployment-main` is a web server and `deployment-poll` container runs a bash script `user-deployment-poll.sh` provided to by a config map (not shown here and is irrelevant). The script runs to completion and exists successfully, so is the container `deployment-poll`. As soon as `deployment-poll` is terminated, the pod is restarted, and it happens multiple times. I don't want the pod to restart after `deployment-poll` is completed.

This is output of `kubectl describe pod <pod-id>`-

```
# --- snip ---
Containers:
  deployment-main:
    Container ID:   docker://ef230d6465c9bc70f07ed90822e573c27ff83ceaeb24439edba27838ce45b81e
    Image:          k8s-registry:31320/my-project-image:19
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://k8s-registry:31320/my-project-image@sha256:f767dce7f405c232e88b599a48bd1fe612db6c1465e805b04c08a093d4fd618e
    Port:           5000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 08 Apr 2021 15:41:05 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from air-run-sa-token-zp8dk (ro)
  deployment-poll:
    Container ID:  docker://31aa899b6cdf83d45933bffca660564f93de6018af7d28fbdb55fe4c63c7b589
    Image:         alpine:3.9
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://alpine@sha256:414e0518bb9228d35e4cd5165567fb91d26c6a214e9c95899e1e056fcd349011
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /bin/sh
    Args:
      /scripts/user-deployment-poll.sh
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Thu, 08 Apr 2021 15:43:47 +0530
      Finished:     Thu, 08 Apr 2021 15:44:04 +0530
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  4
    Environment:
      DEPLOYMENT_NAME:           my-project-19-deployment
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME:  <set to the key 'username' in secret 'air-run-service-account-basic-auth'>  Optional: false
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'password' in secret 'air-run-service-account-basic-auth'>  Optional: false
# --- snip ---
```

It cleary shows that `deployment-poll` is completed and terminated. It is currently in `Waiting` state due to `CrashLoopBackOff`.

#### Edit

The `deployment-poll` container checks the status of `deployment-main` container. As soon as `deployment-main` reaches a particular state, `deployment-poll` calls a service on the cluster notifying that the pod is ok and then it terminates. In other words, both the containers should start at the same time. In the case of init containers, the main container will be run after init container completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an expected behavior as the `Deployment` controller ensures that the `replicas` number of pods defined in its `spec` is always in the `Ready` state. Failing which, it will try to restart the
failing containers using the `Backoff` algorithm.

You could make use of [`Init-containers`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) that does the job of setting up things before the main container starts.

---

Based on the update, I am afraid the `Deployment` strategy will not work for your case. You should instead consider creating a separate [`Job`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) resource with the logic of polling the application running in the `Deployment` and do the necessary one time job.

Comment: Unfortunately, the init-container does not satisfy the requirement. Please see the edited question.

Comment: Hm, I was thinking the same. **Job** will do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, :)  the `Job` resource type would also do the trick. The same case can also be achieved with one deployment having only InitContainer and the other one having only  Container.

Comment: that is a bit of an overkill perhaps.. why use a deployment with no container to achieve the behavior of a job resource?

Comment: hehe :) , can't argue with that either! Job resource type is definitely better answer. Deserves an upvote for sure :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) once your container terminated successfully POD wont restart.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-name
  labels:
    key: value
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      key: value
  template:
    metadata:
      key: value
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: deployment-main
          image: deployment-image-here
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 5000
              protocol: TCP
      initContainers:
        - name: deployment-poll
          image: alpine:3.9
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: [ "/bin/sh" ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the init-container does not satisfy the requirement. Please see the edited question.

Comment: use single container and deploy other one as deployment or job or conrjob as per need instead of managing both in single deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `deployment-poll` has to run only once, you can use the [init-containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to run the bash script. The container will perform its job and exit and the pod will not restart.

In your case its restarting because the kubernetes tries to maintain the state of deployment which in your case requires both the containers to be running at all time. But you want the second container to perform its job and exit.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-name
  labels:
    key: value
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      key: value
  template:
    metadata:
      key: value
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: air-run-sa
      containers:
        - name: deployment-main
          image: deployment-image-here
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 5000
              protocol: TCP
      initContainers:
        - name: deployment-poll
          image: alpine:3.9
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: [ "/bin/sh" ]
          args:
            - /scripts/user-deployment-poll.sh
```

This is only useful if the script part has to run first. Otherwise we should try the `Job` resource type to run the bash container and `Deployment` resource type to run the other container. Of-course the metadata of the Job resource type should change accordingly.

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: deployment-poll
          image: alpine:3.9
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: [ "/bin/sh" ]
          args:
            - /scripts/user-deployment-poll.sh
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

And the other resource type should be deployment.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-name
  labels:
    key: value
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      key: value
  template:
    metadata:
      key: value
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: air-run-sa
      containers:
        - name: deployment-main
          image: deployment-image-here
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 5000
              protocol: TCP
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the init-container does not satisfy the requirement. Please see the edited question.

Comment: Why don't you use different deployments in that case? You will have different pods running and doing the same job. I thought you want the bash script to run first.

Comment: btw, I tried to use this strategy and it fails with the following error: `error: error validating "stdep.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec): missing required field "containers" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`, it seems the containers field is mandatory for `Deployments` and it appears we can't have a deployment without a main container.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. I think Job is the better approach for this. Let me remove the Deployment part.

Comment: Updated the answer now. So that it can help others.